Humans allowed to engage mida k'negged mida?
In my related question, What is the difference between mida k'negged mida and nekama, it was brought that the point of midda k'negged mida (one of the points, at least), is to help someone wake up to their negative behaviour.
This would make it an effective tool for humans to do to each other. However, as that question asks, for humans, that might count, or come uncomfortably close to revenge, which is an issur d'oraissa.
Nonetheless, is there any precedent for humans to do it to each other, to help each other understand what they are doing wrong? In any context, whether it be on the level of the court, or in interpersonal relationships, or in chinuch?
Please quote sources, not looking for personal opinions for this :)

I think I've more or less answered that in your other question

עין תחת עין שן תחת שן

The retribution principle "Eye for Eye", aka "Mida K'Neged Mida" is NOT a Halachic procedure it is more of a teleological basis of a conduct. We do see that the Halachah allows people to grab the property of others if they feel mistreated "עביד איניש דינא לנפשיה" see https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A9_%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%94# IIRC, a Cohen can grab person's domestic animal if he feels that he wasn't given enough tithes.

Are you asking specifically for all humans or Jews only according to Jewish law? I thought to edit the title.

I do not think that mida k'neged mida is a good term. We do not have precise measurement. Even sensitivity to pain is different for various people. There should be a better term for it, like defending interests, keeping barrier etc.

Mida k’neged mida in Exodus 21 is a legal principle, not something that one person does to another, much less a tool. The Torah tells us “a life for a life” because that is the din, not because it endorses revenge. Even when a punishment serves as a deterrent, the point is not revenge. The Torah tolerates rather than endorses, for example, the one who avenges a relative’s blood, and this is why we had arei miklat.
